# Django: Appending reverse OneToOne relational object to a queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have an app that has commenting with each `Comment` object attached to the django `User` model. However, I have important information in the `UserProfile` model (an extra OneToOne model attached to each `User`) such as a user's occupation/title that I would want to easily be accessible from the queryset of the comment objects. What is the best way I can do this in django?

I do to get all comments on a specific page:

```
commentset = Comment.objects.filter(pagetag=page_instance)
```

I need to use something similar to django's annotation function on the above queryset to append an extra property to  each comment object in the queryset which is the reverse OneToOne lookup for the User model to the UserProfile model.

My comment object that has a tag to the django user model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    usertag = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

the profile model that is attached to each user:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=(('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female'), ('other', 'other')), blank=True, null=True)
    editnumber = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    usertag = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profileisverified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    usertitle = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length= 40, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.usertag.first_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to access the profile with `comment.usertag.userprofile` instead of storing it.